# This program I wrote in Java is taking a long time to run ( I haven't seen the results yet)

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, while-loop

Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong here? This java program is taking a very long time to run, so long that I haven't seen the result yet.

```
/* Returns all the factors of a given number */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Object;

class factors{
    public static ArrayList<Integer> factorList;

    public static void get_factors(int num){
        factorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i = 2;
        while(i < num)
        {
            if (num%i == 0)
            {
                factorList.add(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int num = 20;
        get_factors(num);

        for(int i = 0; i < factorList.size(); i++)
        {
            int element = factorList.get(i);
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you think about the factors they always occur in pairs, so for 20 you have (2,10) and (4,5). So when you find that 2 divides into 20 you know that 20/2 is also a factor. This means you only need to check factors up to the square root of the number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You increment `i` only if it is `num%i == 0`, therefore for `i=3` you stop incrementing it and while-loop never ends.

You want this :

```
        if (num%i == 0)
        {
            factorList.add(i);                
        }
        i++;
```

Note also, that there is no reason to use while-loop.

This is more logical solution :

```
public static void get_factors(int num) {
    factorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            factorList.add(i);
        }            
    }
}
```

Also, you should consider, if the factorList initialisation should be in get_factors method, I think you should move it into class

```
class factors{
    public static ArrayList<Integer> factorList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void get_factors(int num) {
    factorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                factorList.add(i);
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice spot removing the 'if'

Comment: I don't understand the bit where you removed the `if`. That will give you numbers in the factor list that will not actually be factors of `num`.

Comment: @G.Bach - yeah, you are right, I was blind :), that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

i is not always begin incremented, if you use a for loop the problem is easier to avoid.

```
public static void get_factors(int num){
    factorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num%i == 0) {
            factorList.add(i);
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your loop:

```
    while(i < num)
    {
        if (num%i == 0)
        {
            factorList.add(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

if `num%i` is not equal to zero `i` will not be incremented and the loop will run again with the same value of `i`.

So move the `i++` out of your `if`-block:

```
    while(i < num)
    {
        if (num%i == 0)
        {
            factorList.add(i);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Or better: use a `for`-loop:

```
for(int i = 1;i<num;i++) {
    if (num%i == 0)
    {
        factorList.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: you still need to define factorList